# Does the Bible say we will die sinning?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin, nature-of-man, death

Psalm 51:5 conveys we are "Born" sinners.

1 John 1:8 conveys we are sinning "Presently".

But is there a scripture that says we will "Die" sinners.

I was under the notion we can't stop sinning, an we will die sinners.
But I can't find a scripture that specifically says in fact we will die sinners..

I know we can stop sinning in a particular way. We can stop stealing, we can stop fornicating etc. 
But we will die sinful men.
 Is there a scripture that (Specifically) says we will "Die" sinners?

I can't find one.

Comment: Are you trying to ask for the Biblical basis against [the Holiness movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holiness_movement)?

Comment: curiuosdannii My friend says we can stop sinning all together. But I was thinking if we could stop sinning all together, we wouldn't need a savior. Jesus fulfill the law for us because we couldn't do it. We were born sinners, we will sin in the present time, and we will die sinners. But I can't find a scripture that specifically says we will die sinners..

Comment: https://www.biblegateway.com/ has a nice search feature.  As it stands, "where in the bible questions..." sound like you have not done enough research and are not willing to do anymore.

Comment: It is an assumption to ascribe confirmation of 'original sin' to Psalm 51:5. I think David is talking about himself and his own mother and circumstances. Not all of humanity. (This will explain the strange I Samuel 16:11 - why was David kept away? The red hair is a clue.) I can see what you are asking but maybe try a different approach.

Comment: I think you should change your question because I can see a 'close' coming. Think of it this way. 'Original sin' (as being the first sin) is to create sins as Eve did in Genesis 3:3 ("nor shall you touch it"). Jesus removed all these human created sins. If you are going to keep inventing sins, you will surely die sinning. But if you understand that Jesus trimmed the excess sins, it is easy to die without sinning.

Comment: Please see: ["Biblical basis" vs "what the Bible says about a subject"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3958) This is very close to "what does the Bible say about ..."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeking a proof text for a personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the one?

> **John 8:24 ESV** I told you that you would die in your sins, for unless you believe that I am he you will die in your sins.

This is Jesus speaking to the Jews.

Comment: I believe John 8:24 is indicating we will not be condemn for our sins if we believe. There's no condemnation for those who are in Christ.. However, we will in fact die sinners, though we want be penalized for it, still, we will die sinners. But I can't find a scripture that says we will in fact "Die" sinners.

Comment: I was talking to my friend, an he said we could stop sinning. But I told him we can stop sinning in various ways, but we will die sinners. I was trying to find a scripture that says we will die sinners. But haven't located one yet..

Comment: We could repent of our sins and die a second later and technically we wouldn't die sinners because the sins are washed away. That's probably why it isn't specified very well.